# What's the idiomatic way to extend a native d3 component like d3.svg.axis()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For a time series visualization in d3, I want to highlight years on the axis. I've accomplished this by making my own xAxis renderer, which invokes the native `axis` function and then implements my own custom logic to format the ticks that it renders.

[image: screenshot]
This is how I've done it ([see working example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zebaxi/71/edit?js,output)):

```
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)

  customXAxis = function(){
    xAxis(this);
    d3.selectAll('.tick', this)
      .classed("year", isYear);
  };

  ...

  xAxis.ticks(10);

  xAxisElement = canvas.append("g")
    .classed("axis x", true)
    .call(customXAxis);
```

This gets the job done, but feels wrong; and it hasn't really extended the axis, it's only wrapped it. Ideally my `customXAxis` would inherit the properties of d3's `axis` component, so I would be able to do things like this:

```
customXAxis.ticks(10)
```

---

Thanks to @meetamit and @drakes for putting this together. Here's what I've ended up with: http://bl.ocks.org/HerbCaudill/ece2ff83bd4be586d9af

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extend" here. For what you're trying to do, you'd have to modify the D3 source code, which you can do of course and then you can make any changes you like.

Comment: By "extend" I mean just what I've shown here: create a custom axis that generates the stuff that the standard axis generates, and then does additional work on that axis - in a way that's callable in the exact same way that the original axis is callable. The approach shown here works, but `xAxis(this)` just feels foreign to d3 for some reason.

Comment: Well `.call()` passes the selection as an argument to the function, so you could use that as well.

Comment: That's true - `this.call(xAxis)` does look more natural in this context.

Comment: Oh I actually meant that you have an argument to `customXAxis` and use that instead of `this`.

Comment: One of the last chapters of Elijah Meeks' book may contain relevant information.

Comment: @Mars nope - Chapter 10 http://www.manning.com/meeks/D3js_ch10.pdf discusses creating custom components using the pattern described here http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/, but not how to extend an existing component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, you can do all that. Following [mbostock's suggestions here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) in conjunction with [`d3.rebind'](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#rebind) you get:

```
// This outer function is the thing that instantiates your custom axis.
// It's equivalent to the function d3.svg.axis(), which instantiates a d3 axis.
function InstantiateCustomXAxis() {
  // Create an instance of the axis, which serves as the base instance here
  // It's the same as what you named xAxis in your code, but it's hidden
  // within the custom class. So instantiating customXAxis also
  // instantiates the base d3.svg.axis() for you, and that's a good thing.
  var base = d3.svg.axis();

  // This is just like you had it, but using the parameter "selection" instead of
  // the "this" object. Still the same as what you had before, but more
  // in line with Bostock's teachings...
  // And, because it's created from within InstantiateCustomXAxis(), you
  // get a fresh new instance of your custom access every time you call
  // InstantiateCustomXAxis(). That's important if there are multiple
  // custom axes on the page.
  var customXAxis = function(selection) {
    selection.call(base);

    // note: better to use selection.selectAll instead of d3.selectAll, since there
    // may be multiple axes on the page and you only want the one in the selection
    selection.selectAll('.tick', this)
      .classed("year", isYear);
  }

  // This makes ticks() and scale() be functions (aka methods) of customXAxis().
  // Calling those functions forwards the call to the functions implemented on
  // base (i.e. functions of the d3 axis). You'll want to list every (or all)
  // d3 axis method(s) that you plan to call on your custom axis
  d3.rebind(customXAxis, base, 'ticks', 'scale');// etc...

  // return it
  return customXAxis;
}
```

To use this class, you just call

```
myCustomXAxis = InstantiateCustomXAxis();
```

You can now also call

```
myCustomXAxis
  .scale(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .ticks(5)
```

And of course the following will continue to work:

```
xAxisElement = canvas.append("g")
  .classed("axis x", true)
  .call(myCustomXAxis);
```

### In summary

That's the idiomatic way to implement classes within d3. Javascript has other ways to create classes, like using the `prototype` object, but d3's own reusable code uses the above method — not the prototype way. And, within that, `d3.rebind` is the way to forward method calls from the custom class to what is essentially the subclass.

Comment: Also, welcome to the 10K club! Glad to have been able to put you over the top. :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the pointage! I though I would trickle towards 10k, but thanks to you I blew right past it :)

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of code inspection and hacking, and talking with experienced d3 people, I've learned that `d3.svg.axis()` is a function (not an object nor a class) so it can't be extended nor wrapped. So, to "extend" it we will create a new axis, run a selection on the base `axis()` to get those tick marks selected, then copy over all the properties from the base `axis()` in one fell swoop, and return this extended-functionality version.

```
var customXAxis = (function() {
  var base = d3.svg.axis();

  // Select and apply a style to your tick marks
  var newAxis = function(selection) {
    selection.call(base);
    selection.selectAll('.tick', this)
      .classed("year", isYear);
  };

  // Copy all the base axis methods like 'ticks', 'scale', etc.
  for(var key in base) {
    if (base.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       d3.rebind(newAxis, base, key);
    }
  }

  return newAxis;
})();
```

`customXAxis` now fully "inherits" the properties of d3's axis component. You can safely do the following:

```
customXAxis
.ticks(2)
.scale(xScale)
.tickPadding(50)
.tickFormat(dateFormatter);

canvas.append("g").call(customXAxis);
```

*With the help of @HerbCaudill's boilerplate code, and inspired by @meetamit's ideas.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kabonokeki/5/

Comment: Thanks, @Drakes. That doesn't work; see http://jsbin.com/zebaxi/72/edit?js,output . The argument of the d3.svg.axis() function is a selection, true, but that code runs before the axis is rendered, not after.

Comment: @HerbCaudill I've updated my solution and jsbin to achieve what you want. I really hope it is what you are looking for. I've been over and over the source code of d3 and talked with others, and this is the best there is.

Comment: thanks for all the work you've put into this. I like way you've automated the rebinding of all the base object's methods - I'll definitely use that.

Comment: I've created an additional bounty since I can't split it between two answers - have to wait until tomorrow to award.

Comment: @HerbCaudill Oh, gosh, that's very generous of you. Thank you so much. Makes my day. It was a pleasure working on this solution for you.